# Modify app name in default splash screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

By default Xcode create a default splash screen with app name on it. 
This default splash screen looks good enough for my application. Except I need to change the app name displayed there.

Fro where I can change the app name displayed on the default splash screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your LaunchScreen.xib under your project files, Click on the file, A interface editor should load, click on the app name label, change the text to something you want or other attributes about the screen.